# How to execute an as3 script from another as3 script in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

I have two as3 files file1.as and file2.as. When a user presses a button in file1.as I want it to execute file2.as. And if someone presses a button in file2.as i want it to go back to file1.as.

Is this possible? Can i attach file2.as to frame 2 and then use gotoAndStop(2) from within file1.as.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are no sample codes in your question, I will try to give a general answer.

In ActionScript 3 .as files (should) correspond to classes, and you should really think this in terms of OOP. Without resorting to scripts in the frames, what you should really be doing is to condense file2.as into a class, or a method inside a class. Then you may instantiate an object of that class (executing your logic in the constructor) when the button is pressed. Or just instantiate it beforehand and call its method when you want it to be executed.

Also, it seems that what you are trying to do would really benefit from the events and listeners concept in AS3.

Edit: modified sample code:

### A.as:

```
class A {
    public var myButton:Sprite;
    protected var myPong:B;

    public function A() {
        myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)
    }

    protected function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        myPong = new B();
        addChild(myPong);
        myPong.addEventListener("pong_closed", onPongClosed);
        myPong.startGame();
    }

    protected function onPongClosed(e:Event):void {
        myPong.removeEventListener("pong_closed", onPongClosed);
        removeChild(myPong);
        myPong = null;
    }
}
```

### B.as:

```
class B {
    public function B() {
        // Game initialization code.
    }

    public function startGame():void {
        trace("ping ... pong ... ping ... pong ... ping");
    }

    public function close():void {
        trace("Closing Pong");
        // Your destruction code goes here.
        // ...
        dispatchEvent(new Event("pong_closed"));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the code. So here are the details: I have actually designed a frame that consists of ir sensors/receivers. I have made two apps for it. One is a scientific calculator and the other is a pong pong game. Its like a touchless pad. There will two options for the user to chose from, either open the calculator or play the game. These are my two classes calculator.as and pingpong.as. I hope i am clear. Thank you.

Comment: OK, this brings to mind two solutions: First, you can make the class B your pong game and instantiate, addChild & start the game like in the code above (I'll modify it a little). This method compiles everything inside a single SWF slightly increasing the file size, but I don't think that would be a huge problem. Secondly, you can just make the game another SWF and use a Loader instance to load it when the user presses the button, but I doubt that it is really necessary in your case.

Comment: but then if someone wants to go to the scientific calculator, how would they do it while in the pong pong game? Do i have to create an event listener for it in the scientific calculator class? Thank you

Comment: That is correct. Please see the sample again, I edited it to reflect this change.